# why CORS request in angular application

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have application using MVC, angular.js , entity framework and Webapi.
My Webapi is in same solution but in different project so it has its own port. In my angular service i tried to call webapi like

```
app.service('MyService', function coursesService($http) {
var self = this;

self.addData = function (data, config) {
    return $http.post('http://localhost:1234/api/Test', JSON.stringify(data), config)
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
       return data;
   })
   .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
       return data;
   });
}
});
```

But when application ran it was throwing error cross origin request. So in my webapi's webapiconfig.cs i had to write below code in Register method

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Then i got rid of this error. But what i would like to know if this is common issue and what is best way to avoid it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS error on same domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain)

Comment: This is how it is. If you put the web api controllers inside the MVC project, like /Controllers/api, you would not have to enable CORS to hit the API.

Comment: The other solution if you want to hide your api, is to post back to your controller and then create a web request to your api using a tool like Refit.  This way, if you decide to split your api onto a separate web server, you would only have to change the configuration file that tells re-fit where to find your api end point.