# Ajax call returning from node JavaScript to jQuery lands on error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have jQuery as client script and node JavaScript server as back-end.

I used to post the request to node server for getting data. Please find my AJAX call below.

My problem is even if my response is set to success it always comes in error function of the jquery.AJAX method.

And error object looks like

[image]

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/uploadcontent/fileUpload',
        type : 'post',
        data : formData,
        enctype : 'multipart/form-data',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        error : function(error,jqXHR, exception) {
            errorMessage(error);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
            console.log(exception +"  :  "+error);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data.sucess){
                successMessage(data.returnMessage);
            } else {
                alert('error');
                if (data.returnObj != null) {

                } else{
                    errorMessage(data.returnMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Now, find below my node JavaScript route for the above request.

```
app.post('/fileupload', function(req, res) {

    var fstream;
    var fileName, bunchId, standard, userKey, subject, unit, chapter, topic;
    req.pipe(req.busboy,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err.code + " (" + err.message + ")");
            return;
        }
    });
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename);          
        fstream = fs.createWriteStream(config.content_upload_path.pdf_path + filename + 'abc');         
        file.pipe(fstream,function(err) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('pipe error due to stream')
                console.log("ERROR: " + err.code + " (" + err.message + ")");
                return;
            }
        });
        fstream.on('close', function () {
            fileName = filename;
            fileObject = file;       
            uploadFile(paramData, res)
            res.redirect('back');
            console.log('method complete')
        });

        fstream.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('stream on error event')
            console.log(err)
            generateWebServiceResponse(res, false, null, 200, err)
            console.log(res);
            res.send()              
        });

    });}
```

generateWebServiceResponse method looks like this:

```
function generateWebServiceResponse(response, isSuccess, result, httpStatus,
    returnMessage) {
response.json({
    isSucess : isSuccess,
    returnObj : result,
    returnMessage : returnMessage,
    resultCode : 0,
    httpStatus : httpStatus
});}
```

Even in case of failure it should land in success function with `isSuccess = false`. But in each case it is landed in error case.

I am also not able to solve access origin error mentioned in the attached image.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You must enable CORS for your route. The simplest way is using [Node.js CORS middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Comment: I have used cors in app.js .. like 
var cors = require('cors');
 app.use(cors());  
And I get rid of that access origin error ... thanks ....

Now, another problem which I defined is : return object is :  object : Object

Comment: Ok .. I got the object which I wanted ! .... But.... in the ajax.done() event  ... not in ajax.success() event ... What can be the reason for that ?