# CSRF filter is blocking the access (from angular , backend : Playframework)

Tags: angular, http, playframework, http-post, csrf

I tried to send data to backend(Playframework ). Csrf filter is blocking my request from fronted (angular). How can I disable it? this warn came in backend -   [warn] p.filters.CSRF - [CSRF] Check failed because text/plain for request /api/add-books

[image]

```
    +nocsrf
    POST   /api/add-book             controllers.HomeController.addBooks()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSHZm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Log.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YslGB.png)

I tried these-

```
play.filters.desabled += play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
play.filters.desabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter"
```

But the problem is still there

Comment: You could probably take a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling is wrong, correct it into:

```
play.filters.disabled += play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter
play.filters.disabled += play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
```

If you are using compile-time dependency injection, configuration above will be ignored. Instead you need put code into your custom ApplicationLoader.

Here is the official documentation:

[Compile Time Default Filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Filters#Compile-Time-Default-Filters)