# Request block by CORS

Tags: node.js, cors

I have an application built on angular and node js and when after login into application, there is an error on fetching data as it is shown me CORS error? how should I resolve this error?

[image]

Comment: Please read this tutorial https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS error on same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by the API running on a different port. See [CORS error on same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain)

Try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers to your API.

This is how this is achieved on [Express](https://expressjs.com/) using [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).

The following allows all origins and methods (this might be too open depending on your requirements).

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: @Vinhaariqbal Looking at the code, is it in production?

Comment: @Vinhaariqbal Can you try replacing the `server.opts('/\.*/', corsHandler, optionsRoute);` lines by the above `app.use` code block (replacing `app` by `server`)?

Comment: @Vinhaariqbal Also, I recommend using environment variables instead of hard coding passphrases. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Yes this is the production code, and i try your advise and let you know.

Comment: @Vinhaariqbal It’s probably a good idea to change the passphrase as it was just leaked in the above link.

Comment: Yeah will do this thing also, first solve that CORS issue.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work? Anymore solution??

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to app running on port 1949 rejecting the request from port 80, bcos it considers as cross origin request. You need to config CORS for the app on port 1949 to access from any origin `origin: "*"`, sample for node js:

```
server.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  })
);
```

Comment: I update my answer, you don't need to set header at ur own, just config the cors is enough

Comment: So I remove all my CORS function and replace it with the code you provide above?