# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

Tested in `Postman` and works fine.
In Browser I get this Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:5081/api/Accounting/GetSales' from origin
> 'https://localhost:44426' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Asp Net Core Project with Angular and .Net6

```
[DisableCors]
[HttpGet("GetSales")]
        public IEnumerable<SaleDto> GetSales()
        {
            var result = _context.Sales.Select(x => new SaleDto
            {
                AccountName = x.Account.Name,
                CategoryName = x.Category.CategoryName,
                SaleDate = x.SaleDate,
                SaleId = x.SaleId,
                SaleValue = x.SaleValue,
            });
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: you have to expose the cors on the server. `DisableCors` defeats that

Comment: Postman does not care about CORS. The browser does. You explicitely disabled CORS for that call, so why do you wonder it doesn't work?

Comment: Tested it without DisableCors and still not working.

Comment: So, have you configured CORS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have the proper entries when you register the middleware?
[Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

You will need to add localhost and the port numbers. I believe the port numbers are currently causing the issue right now.  If both sites were on the same port number you might not get this issue.
Also, see the answers for CORS error on same domain.
[CORS error on same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain)

Also, you want to enable CORS not disable it. CORS relaxes the security measures so your code can reach across ports.

Answer (score 6):

What works for me was putting

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );
```

before

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

in your `Program.cs` or `startup.cs`

then you can alter your configrations

Comment: According to the Microsoft docs `app.UseCors()` should be placed after `app.UseRouting()`
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0#:~:text=The%20call%20to%20UseCors%20must%20be%20placed%20after%20UseRouting%2C%20but%20before%20UseAuthorization.

Comment: @GeorgeFeakes I noticed that too but I couldn't get it to work that way... The solution of Wowo Ot works, but I don't know why. I don't know why MS's intended way doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to check is make sure your origin is spelled out exactly.

I had "http://localhost:4200/" as the origin somehow, instead of "http://localhost:4200".

Took a lot of hours to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

In Appsetting.json file
{
"AllowOrigins": "https://localhost:4200"
}

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       
        var allowOrigins = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowOrigins");
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(allowOrigins)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowCredentials();
            });
            options.AddPolicy("AllowHeaders", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(allowOrigins)
                        .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.ContentType, HeaderNames.Server, HeaderNames.AccessControlAllowHeaders, HeaderNames.AccessControlExposeHeaders, "x-custom-header", "x-path", "x-record-in-use", HeaderNames.ContentDisposition);
            });
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "DatingApp", Version = "v1" });
        });
        //authentication
        

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DatingApp v1"));

        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //    }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        //authentication
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: strangely, .AllowCredentials didn't pop up in the context sensitive help...  but when I trusted your answer and added it, it worked like a champ...  so thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I tried changing the header from the part of the front-end from where I was doing the calls and then directly to the controller but what worked for me was changing the Start.cs file of the API project and add the following. I recommend trying it first in localhost and then deploying the changes where you actually have the API.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly string _MyCors = "MyCors";
    .
    .
    .
    public void ConfigureServices(...)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        //Under your services.AddControllers();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: _MyCors, builder =>
            {
                //for when you're running on localhost
                builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost") 
                .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();


                //builder.WithOrigins("url from where you're trying to do the requests")
            });
        });
    }
    public void Configure(.....)
    {
        //before the app.UseAuthorization & app.UseEndpoints
        app.UseCors(_MyCors);
    }
}
```