# No Luck getting Spring Security with Cors to work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

yes I know I am not the first one to ask this question, but as I have now been trying to fix this issue and not been able to for the past 16h I do not know any further. The problem is as follows. I have a WebSecurityConfig Class like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
  @Autowired
  UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    return authProvider;
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
    return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*"); // Zugriff von jeder URL erlauben
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config); // Für alle Pfade anwenden
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
        .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll().requestMatchers("/api/health/**")
            .permitAll().requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

I have been trying to get cors to work properly but it just does not want to work. As far as I understand the problem is that spring security checks cors before making any more configuration meaning that the request does not get to the corsFilter that I have defined. Still all the solutions that I have found are eather contraticting, to old to be relevant or sometimes seem to have no effect on anything.

Below you can also find The Controller in question:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private SequenceGeneratorService generatorService;


    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt,
                userDetails.getId(),
                userDetails.getUsername(),
                userDetails.getEmail(),
                roles));
    }
[REDACTED]
```

I hope some of you might be able to point me in the right direction or help me find a solution to my problem.

I already tried implementing a varity of solutions such as:

1. Defining the @CrossOrigin at the Method or Class Level
2. Defining a CorsConfig Class
3. Adding a varity of corsFilters, corsSourceSomethings to the WebSecurityConfig

Comment: Show your request with headers. Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs.

Comment: Why did you write such custom code instead of using the official code from the Spring Security Reference? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/cors.html

Comment: Remove `corsFilter` and use `corsConfigurationSource`.

Comment: You have both a `CorsFilter` but define `http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());` so which is it? Use one or the other not both.

Answer (score 1):

Some days ago i had a similar issue, the browser tools console showed me an error of Cors CrossOrigin (if you can post the error that you are getting it could be easier to find a solution (:) and i started looking at everything related with this.
Some days later i realized that the problem was not on CORS, the problem was that the firewall was blocking the access from ports 8085 so the console showed the CORS error.

Check if you are accessing the right ports and so on, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966707/cors-error-on-same-domain) you can find a similar error that happened to me, CORS can sometimes be really generic.
I hope it helps you in anyway!

Comment: The error you have linked does look very similar to mine, I will recreate the error and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both crosFilter bean and http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults());

I suggest to keep just one of them.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I tried removing one or the other but unfortunatly that did not seem to fix it, still thank you.