# retrieving data from python bottle using ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cors, bottle

I am trying an html page to interact with a python script which returns a json string, using ajax/jquery. I installed bottle for the basic functionality of url routing.

The problem is that my browser shows that my ajax script is recieving a content-length of 5 (which is the string "tring" (see server.py function showAll()) but somehow its not stored in the variable result(see function loader in script.js) and hence I cannot use the returned data.

can anyone tell me what is going wrong..

my html file looks like

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            magpie
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">loader();</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I call load() instead of loader() in this file the content is displayed.

the ajax script:

**script.js**

```
function loader()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('http://[localhost]:1111/', function(result){
            alert('success');
            $('#main').html(result);
        });
    });
}

function load()
{
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
            var output = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                output += '<h3>' + val.device + '  ' + val.status + '</h3>';
            })
            $('#main').html(output);
        });
    });
}
```

the two python scripts are :

**server.py**

```
from bottle import get, post, request, run, response
import devices

@get('/')
def showAll():
    # return devices.data
    return "tring"

@post('/act')
def act():
    deviceId = request.forms.get('deviceId')
    devices.changeState(deviceId)
    return

run(host = "[localhost]", port = 1111)
```

**devices.py**

```
import json

data = json.load(open('data.json', 'r+'))
nos = len(data) # Number of devices

def changeState(id):
    state = data[id]['status']
    if state == 'on':
        data[id]['status'] = 'off'
    else:
        data[id]['status'] = 'on'

    json.dump(data, open('data.json', 'w'))

    return 1
```

and finally my json file(if it matters):

```
{"B1": {"device": "fan", "status": "on"}, "B3": {"device": "light", "status": "off"}, "B2": {"device": "fan", "status": "on"}}
```

Loading http://[localhost]:1111/ in browser shows the returned string "tring".Also the page loads only in firefox while other browsers show some allow-acces-origin error.

This is a screenshot of my browser :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable the accessControlAllowOrigin header (thanks to @user3202272, I got the hint from your answer).

Added a few lines to my server.py file and that was it.

Now it looks like

**server.py**

```
from bottle import Bottle, request, response, run
import devices

app = Bottle()

@app.hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

@app.get('/')
def show():
    return devices.data
    # return "tring"

@app.post('/act')
def act():
    deviceId = request.forms.get('deviceId')
    devices.changeState(deviceId)
    return

app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 1111)
```

So basically the problem was with the CORS. You can read more about it here
https://gist.github.com/richard-flosi/3789163

[Bottle Py: Enabling CORS for jQuery AJAX requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17262170/593047)

thanks to everyone..!! :D

Answer (score 3):

how is your browser recieving "tring" when you are returning "string" from your python script.

I think you will have to set

```
accessControlAllowCredentials true
```

I suppose

Comment: oh yes I had changed the "string" to "tring" just in case there is some keyword problem or something...edited it now..thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This is a great point, but it should be a comment on the original post rather than an answer.

Comment: @ron.rothman sorry for that..but I dont have the minimum privileges required to do comment on a question

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not returning json; it's returning text/html.

Instead of this:

```
return "tring"
```

return a `dict`, like this:

```
return {"result": "tring"}
```

Comment: that would have been the case if I would have been returning json, the problem is that it my ajax is not recieving any type of data leave json type..Thanks anyways.

Comment: yes, i was about to suggest that you look at CORS (http://stackoverflow.com/q/17262170/593047), but i see you found the solution yourself.  cool--cheers.