# how to solve json error : SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {"products":[{"title":"xyz","id":1718,"created_at?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, callback

i have some code in ajax call like below

```
$.ajax({
                url: query_string,
                cache: true,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false, // must be set to false
                success: function (data, success) {
                alert(jquery.parseJSON(data));
                  alert('success');
                  //alert(data);
                  //alert(success);
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                error :function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) { 
                    var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
                    alert(err);
                },
                complete: function (jqxhr, textStatus ){
                //alert( "complete: " + JSON.stringify(jqxhr)+" "+ textStatus );
                }
            });
```

when i run this code into firefox with fire bug. firebug shows response in perect json format but shows following error in firebug

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"products":[{"title":"xyz","id":1718,"created_at
```

so how can i solve it??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456146/ajax-call-and-clean-json-but-syntax-error-missing-before-statement

Comment: The response data is parsed for you.  Get rid of `jquery.parseJSON` and just `alert(data)`

Comment: parsererror, Error: jQuery111005023312801262618_1397224574072 was not called above error shows in alert of error function

Answer (score 3):

You are telling jQuery to process the response as JSONP:

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

… but the response is JSON, not JSONP.

Get rid of the `p` or get rid of the `dataType` line entirely and let jQuery determine the data type from the `Content-Type` of the response (which should be `application/json`).

Comment: but if i use json there is no any response cause it is cross domain

Comment: If you want to use JSONP, then the server you are requesting the data from has to give you JSONP. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for alternatives.

Comment: parsererror, Error: jQuery111005023312801262618_1397224574072 was not called above error shows in alert of error function

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
dataType: 'jsonp',
```

to

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Because you are getting JSON, not JSONP, back.

Comment: but if i use json there is no any response cause it is cross domain

Comment: Does the URL that your requesting allow you at add callback=? to the URL string? If it is setup correctly that would return JSONP.

Comment: To the end of the URL string, so you would add &callback=? Many API's implement that for returning JSONP

Comment: i had add but same result

Comment: parsererror, Error: jQuery111005023312801262618_1397224574072 was not called above error shows in alert of error function

Comment: You may have to contact the site to see if they can return JSONP. If not, you can always look at CORS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262170/bottle-py-enabling-cors-for-jquery-ajax-requests

Answer (score 1):

In your controller make sure that you render the format correctly.
example:

```
def view_product
    data = Product.find params[:id]
    render :json =>  data, :callback => params[:callback]
end
```

In your render method, there must have the **:callback** parameter otherwise it will render in json instead of jsonp.

Comment: Yes, you're right on this. You must also disable `protect_from_forgery` on that action to make it work.